# can't parse parse time string with posix-style timezone in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, posix

I have a time string like this: `2013-08-22 16:56:19 Etc/GMT`

I need to parse it to a datetime object. I'm getting hung up on the posix-style time zone, which I can't get Python to natively grok.

Here are a couple of attempts and their failures. I'm including the timezone-stripped version first to show the parsing is otherwise correct.

**datetime.strptime**

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-08-22 16:56:19 UTC", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 22, 16, 56, 19)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-08-22 16:56:19 Etc/GMT", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2013-08-22 16:56:19 Etc/GMT' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

**time.strptime**

```
>>> time.strptime("2013-08-22 16:56:19 UTC", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=16, tm_min=56, tm_sec=19, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=234, tm_isdst=0)
>>> time.strptime("2013-08-22 16:56:19 Etc/GMT", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 454, in _strptime_time
return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2013-08-22 16:56:19 Etc/GMT' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

**dateutil.parser**

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("2013-08-22 16:56:19")
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 22, 16, 56, 19)
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("2013-08-22 16:56:19 Etc/GMT")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 720, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 310, in parse
    raise ValueError("unknown string format")
ValueError: unknown string format
```

### possible solutions/avenues tried

**tzinfos**

It seems like [dateutil's tzinfos argument](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) should be perfect for this, but it doesn't work either... or I'm misreading the trace and doing something wrong. ([I used this as an example](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/995/))

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("2013-08-22 16:56:19 Etc/GMT", tzinfos={ 'Etc/GMT': pytz.timezone('UTC') })
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 720, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 310, in parse
    raise ValueError("unknown string format")
ValueError: unknown string format
```

**tzinfos, round two**

It seems like [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766400/659298) is getting towards the usage of tzinfos that I might need. I tried the simplified version of the above (where value=offset seconds). Still fails.

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("2013-08-22 16:56:19 Etc/GMT", tzinfos={ 'Etc/GMT': 0 })
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 720, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 310, in parse
    raise ValueError("unknown string format")
ValueError: unknown string format
```

**do it the wrong way**

I could always use something like regex or string matching to find and change this timezone, but it feels *wrong*.

**red herrings**

The common problem with the posix ETC/xxx timezones is that [they have reversed signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008960/pytz-and-etc-gmt-5). This is a UTC ("no offset") posix time zone, and many of the questions I've found that deal with "etc" have to do with this reversed offset.

Comment: Python does not grok time zones in any good way any case, using time zones in python is like wanting to shoot yourself in the foot, but being unable, shoot yourself in the head instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

- parse date string without the timezone part into `datetime` object via `strptime()`
- parse timezone string into `pytz` timezone
- update `tzinfo` on the datetime object via `replace()`

---

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

date_string = "2013-08-22 16:56:19"
tz_string = "Etc/GMT"


dt = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT'))
print dt
```

prints:

```
2013-08-22 16:56:19+00:00
```

This actually correctly understands and reverses signs in the POSIX timezone format, for example:

```
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT-1'))
print dt  # prints 2013-08-22 16:56:19+01:00
```

Comment: to break the string into two parts I'd have to either match that exact string or try to approximate it. This falls into "do it the wrong way" to me, but it's an option.

Comment: Well, `pytz` handles this timezone format. I think this is an option for you.

Comment: the problem is knowing what those TZs might be to break the string apart. Still, it's probably the best option. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @tedder42: use `tz.localize(dt)` instead of `dt.replace(tzinfo=tz)` (the latter fails for many timezones (though it works for UTC)).