# Parsing a date string containing a timezone using joda-time

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to parse a date string using joda time and unfortunately I can't find a way to parse the timezone.

Here my latest attempt:

```java
String s = "2013-09-20 13:23:50 Etc/GMT";
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ").parseDateTime(s)
```

results in

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2013-09-20 13:23:50 Etc/GMT" is malformed at "Etc/GMT"
```

Where is the error in my pattern?

Comment: Which time zone is `Etc/GMT`? I know `GMT` but what is `Etc`?

Comment: Wich version of `joda-time` are you using? I tried your example (with version 2.3) and it is executing successfully!

Comment: @AaronDigulla It's a Posix thing see also here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4009126/817385

Comment: @AaronDigulla it's in the docs http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html

Comment: @mabbas I'm using 2.1

Comment: :-/ Then it should work. `zzz` will not work: "Time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed." ((docs)[http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html]). So `ZZZ` should be the correct pattern. Odd. Can you try with 2.2? Maybe it's a bug (but I doubt it).

Comment: @AaronDigulla hmm downloaded 2.2 but the result is the same... I hate stuff like this. Probably a minor thing you can only miss :/.

Comment: Create a unit test and step through the code with a debugger. Or look at the code and try to find out where it tries to parse time zones and write a unit test for that to see what happens.

Comment: Works for me out of the box too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Joda-Time` library with version `2.0` or later.
This feature was added in version `2`.
See [release notes](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/upgradeto200.html)  1.6 -> 2.0.

> - Allow 'Z' and 'ZZ' in format patterns to parse 'Z' as '+00:00' [2827359]
> - Support parsing of date-time zone IDs like Europe/London
> - Support parsing of date-time zone names like "EST" and "British Summer Time"   These names are not unique, so the new API methods on
>     the builder require you   to pass in a map listing all the names you
>     want to be able to parse.   The existing method is unaltered and does
>     not permit parsing.

Comment: Turns out my original problem was a nasty classpath problem, that caused an older version of joda time to be used.

Thanks for the tip Ilya that pointed me to the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

To parse datetime string with time zone you can use next for [Java]:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
      // z is timezone name
      .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z") 
      // special map to map names to time zones
      .appendTimeZoneName(new HashMap() {{
          put("UTC", DateTimeZone.UTC);
      }}) 
      .toParser
```

or [Scala]

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
      .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z")
      .appendTimeZoneName(Map("UTC" -> DateTimeZone.UTC))
      .toParser
```