# Issue with code when using datetime and timezone

Tags: python, date, datetime, pytz

I have a list of strings called 'entries'. Each entry includes a date and time in a format like this: 'Mon Jun 15 17:52:03 2015'

I'm parsing the dates/times from each entry with regex and then I need to put them into python's datetime format and change the timezone to UTC (which is local time +4 hrs). Here's my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

local = pytz.timezone("Etc/GMT+4")
localdate = [None]*len(entries)
local_dt = [None]*len(entries)
utc_dt = [None]*len(entries)
utdate = [None]*len(entries)

for i in range(len(entries)):
    localdate[i] = datetime.strptime(re.search(r'\w{3}\s*?\w{3}\s*?\d{1,2}\s*?
\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*?\d{4}', entries[i]).group(0), "%c")
    local_dt[i] = local.localize(localdate[i], is_dst=None)
    utc_dt[i] = local_dt[i].astimezone(pytz.utc)
    utdate[i] = utc_dt[i].strftime("%c")

utdate = map(str, utdate)
print utdate
```

It seems to work well line-by-line if I go through and print each step, but once it gets to the last step it reverts back to the original format of the dates/times rather than the python datetime format of 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'. Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

You're formatting the `datetime` object into a string with `utdate[i] = utc_dt[i].strftime("%c")`. The `%c` code [formats the date according to the system's localization settings](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), not the format you're expecting.

The standard string representation of a `datetime` object will generate the format you're looking for – you can get a string from `str(some_datetime)`, or `print(some_datetime)` to print it to the console.

### Timezones

This is notoriously hard to keep track of, but you may want to double check which timezone you're using. As is, your code will take an input time and give an output time that's 4 hours earlier. If I'm understanding correctly, you expect it the other way around. You should know that the ["Etc" timezones are labelled oppositely for weird reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008960/pytz-and-etc-gmt-5/4009126), and you may want to change the timezone used. It's a different question, but using a location-based timezone instead of a UTC offset may be a good idea for things like DST support.

### Improvements

You can simplify and clarify what you're trying to do here with a few changes. It makes it a bit more "Pythonic" as well.

```
input_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y' # Change 1
converted_entries = [] # Change 2

for entry in entries: # Change 3
    local_date = datetime.strptime(entry, input_format) # Change 1 (continued)
    # Change 4
    localized_date = local.localize(local_date)
    utc_date = localized_date.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    converted_entries.append(utc_date)

utdate = map(str, converted_entries)
print utdate
```

#### Changes

1. Use a [strftime/strptime formatter](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). `strftime` and `strptime` are designed to parse strings, ordinarily regular expressions shouldn't be needed to process them first. The same goes for output formats – if specific format is needed that's not provided with a built-in method like `datetime.isoformat`, use a formatter.
2. In Python there's no need to initialize a list a length ahead of time (or with `None`). `list_var = []` or `list_var = list()` will give you an empty list that will expand on demand.
3. Typically it's best and simplest to just iterate over a list, rather than jump through hoops to get a loop counter. It's more readable, and ultimately less to remember.

   - If you do need a counter, use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate), *e.g.*: `for i, entry in enumerate(entries):`
4. Use scoped variables. Temporary values like `localdate` and `localdt` can just be kept inside the `for` loop. Technically it's wasting memory, but more importantly it keeps the code simpler and more encapsulated.
5. If the values are needed for later, then do what I've done with the `converted_entries` list. Initialize it outside the loop, then just append the value to the list each time through.

No need for counter variables:

```
localized_dates = []
for # omitted ...
    localized_date = local.localize(local_date)
    localized_dates.append(localized_date)
```

I hope that's helpful for you. The beauty of Python is that it can be pretty simple, so just embrace it

Comment: Thanks for the help! Although one thing remains unsolved. I implemented your improvements but the utdate comes out in this format: '2015-06-15 21:52:03+00:00'. The timezone change is successful and the format is good, but I need to get rid of that pesky '+00:00'. Any ideas how? I'm running python 2.7.6 so %z doesn't work.

Comment: Read the [strftime format](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) docs I linked in point #1. That's what you use to output a date to a particular format. In your case, you'd want something like `output_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. Then use that with `strftime` to get the format you want. You'll have to change the `map` operation to something like `map(lambda k: k.strftime(output_format), converted_entries)`.

Comment: @WynneT if that fixed it, please mark the question as answered :)